# How to send newsletters?

Tags: email, website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mailing list with subscribe/unsubscribe features](https://superuser.com/questions/13683/mailing-list-with-subscribe-unsubscribe-features)

We need to send newsletters for our website users, did you try or recommend a certain program or web service to send these newsletters?

Our newsletters contain html, images.

Also i am not sure if superuser is the right place to ask this question, or should i ask on serverfault or stackoverflow. So advice me.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/13683/mailing-list-with-subscribe-unsubscribe-features

Comment: Do you want to send an email blast out to your current users or new users that will sign up? If both, we'll need to know what type of Database you are using.

Comment: i have a list of my users in csv file, and will import in the new newsletters service to send to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company uses [Blue Sky](http://www.blueskyfactory.com/). This service may be overdoing it for you, but it works great for us. Also, you may want to try [Fusemail](http://www.fusemail.com). They have an email campaign tool also. If you want more of a variety, just google email campaign.

As far as getting the mailing list out of your web server, you would have to extract the email addresses from your database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do something like a mail merge.  MS Word supports mail merge right out of the box.  There is no need to use a special program for this purpose as you can send them via your regular email address.  The content of the message can be set to HTML in your mail client so you should have no problems with the content of the message.

[Mail Merge Tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA010349201033.aspx)

[Yet another Tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051872571033.aspx)

The two links above should help you.

Comment: MS Word-generated HTML?

Comment: MS Word does indeed do HTML

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/13683/mailing-list-with-subscribe-unsubscribe-features/13684#13684): I would recommend [YourMailingListProvider](http://YourMailingListProvider.com).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recommend [campaign monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) highly enough. They are based in Australia, one of my ex-coworkers is a tester there, they are referred to as the "Fog creek of Australia" for their  offices and they are behind the recent fixoutlook.org campaign as well as making great software for this purpose.

Their customers include Apple, twitter, facebook, Yahoo, HP and Intel.

Answer (score 0):

[iContact](http://www.icontact.com) is a service that lets you run email campaigns for your clients. I haven't used their service to send emails, but I am on a few lists of companies that use their services to send marketing material. I have used a trial of theirs to test it out (it was for a project, not for real uses). They let you send out HTML emails and surveys. I'm not sure what the pricing is for it though.